# VMware Workstation stability on Linux

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation

I'd like to know if VMware Workstation 10 is running stable under Linux Debian or Ubuntu!?

I'm planning to build a new server for visualization purposes to run different VM's like Windows Server. These VM's will mostly be accessed remotely via the VNC. Would you recommend the use of VMware Workstation on a Linux distribution. Or is there maybe another product out there that would fit in?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using VMware Player under Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 to run three VMs for a while now. The only issue I had was a memory allocation problem, which was not the fault of the VM environment. I initially tried with Oracle Virtualbox, but was unable to get it functioning correctly. This was using both the a `wget` from Oracle site and downloaded through Ubuntu Software Manager.

This may have been a specific issue with my host, but should you have success here you can have a look at some comparisons between these applications from [xmodulo](http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/vmware-player-vs-virtualbox-feature-comparison.html).

I am currently using VMware Workstation on my Windows 7 laptop without incident, although I only have four VMs and have yet to do extensive testing.

I would suggest this is a stable product to run under the conditions I outlined. VMware are even nice enough to provide a nice breakdown of the process for getting this up and running. You can find it [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_install_linux.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comparison link. Seems to be stable enough on Linux :)

Comment: @MrMAG | I would agree. Do make sure you mark the question as answered for anyone else coming along. Have fun virtualising :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using VMware Workstation in Debian for years, from version 5.5 to 10.0, and it's been quite stable.  There's a time-limited free trial available if you'd like to test it yourself.

Comment: My university offers me a license for the full version of Workstation. Btw, I'm already using it on Windows about 2 years and I'm very satisfied with it. But want to switch over to an Linux environment.